# Is there a touchpad event handler in Java?

Tags: java, event-listener, touchpad

Is there any event listener for touchpad in java? I am designing an application which counts the number of taps entered by the user using a laptop's touchpad.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623777/how-to-implement-a-java-swing-application-to-touch-screen

Comment: Are these not mapped to mouse clicks?  You can get events for each click, or double/triple/quadruple clicks.

Comment: MouseListener registers the event if I tap with one finger but if I am tapping a rythm with two fingers, it fails to register the touch event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TUIO](http://www.tuio.org/?software).  There are a number of Java implementations out there.

Comment: I am going through the docs for implementing TUIO. I will update with my findings. Thanks.